# Set bash as default shell with option to enter into fish

Tags: command-line, bash, fish

I've seen a few questions as to how to enter into bash while fish is the default shell. I actually want to do the opposite. I currently have fish as my default shell, but would like to return to bash as my default. However, I do not want to uninstall fish and would like the option to enter into a shell session with fish at my discretion. Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: check this may help you http://superuser.com/questions/46748/how-do-i-make-bash-my-default-shell-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could change your default shell to bash by typing in the following line:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

You will probably need to log out and log back in for the settings to take effect.

Then if you wanted to run fish, it would just be the command `fish` at a bash prompt.

More information can be found at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ChangingShells

Comment: Or `exec fish`, if you want your terminal/session to close when you exit `fish` (instead of dropping back to your original shell).